# JQuery Cycle2 plugin layout within HTML slide broken only in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, jquery-cycle2

http://stepladderuk.com/dev/wtf/

This is a slider using the cycle2 plugin, instead of rotating between images, this rotates between divs. `div.content-slide`

This works fine in all browsers, even IE8!! but try it in Safari, it doesn't like it.

When I disable cycle2, this happens (in Safari)

[image: cycle2 Safari]

This shows that when cycle2 doesn't initialise, the layout of the panels maintains. So isn't a layout/CSS issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: Which OS? Error in console?

Comment: OS X 10.8.5

No error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right in some way, but to fix this issue you still have to look for the css way.
In your css file `main.css`
Add one line like below:

```
#space_plans .cycle-slideshow .content-slide {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%; //Add this
      position: relative; 
}
```

The problem is that the slider plugin stopped Safari from inheriting width from parent or calculating from child content.